Displaying java terminal output into Javafx textfield (with inputs)
I am trying to make software which will allow the user to create and read their recipes. To achieve this I am saving the data inputed by the user in .txt files. My main class with the reading/writing methods works fine, but currently all inputs/outputs are displayed in the terminal.
I am trying to build a gui for my software and I decided to use JavaFX. I have created buttons for the methods of my main class and a textfield for inputs as well as a textarea for outputs. But whenever I press the button for executing any of the methods the program becomes unresponsive and crashes. Is there a way to fix this?
Here is the code of the gui file :)
public class guitest extends Application {
    private TextArea outputArea;
    private TextField inputField;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group(); //Creates the root node
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600, Color.rgb(66, 66, 66)); //Creates the scene

        // Add text title
        Text title = new Text("Flavor Saver");
        title.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 24));
        title.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        title.setX((scene.getWidth() - title.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()) / 2);
        title.setY(50);
        root.getChildren().add(title);

        // Add output area
        outputArea = new TextArea();
        outputArea.setPrefSize(600, 500);
        root.getChildren().add(outputArea);

        // Add input field
        inputField = new TextField();
        inputField.setPrefSize(600, 50);
        root.getChildren().add(inputField);

        // Redirect console output to output area
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        System.setOut(printStream);

        //Buttons
        GridPane buttonPane = new GridPane();
        buttonPane.setHgap(10);
        buttonPane.setVgap(10);
        buttonPane.setLayoutX((scene.getWidth() - 300) / 2); // Center horizontally
        buttonPane.setLayoutY(100); // Set vertical position

        Button createButton = new Button("Create recipe");
        Button readButton = new Button("Read recipe");
        Button editButton = new Button("Edit recipe");

        buttonPane.add(createButton, 0, 0);
        buttonPane.add(readButton, 1, 0);
        buttonPane.add(editButton, 2, 0);

        root.getChildren().addAll(buttonPane);

        createButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Creating recipe...");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        FlavorSaverApp.createRecipe(scanner);
        scanner.close();
        });

        readButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Reading recipe...");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        FlavorSaverApp.displayRecipeChooser(scanner);
        scanner.close();
        });

        editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Editing recipe...");
            // Will be added in future
        });

        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon.png"));
        stage.setTitle("FlavorSaver: The only recipe app you will ever need");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Update output area with console output
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String text = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
                outputArea.appendText(text);
                byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}


Your fragment appears to be updating the scene graph from a background thread, which will interfere with GUI updates. Alternatively, consider a more conventional editor design using a TextArea and FileChooser, for example.

If you are going to do GUI app development, you are going to have to move away from Scanner. Looking for something in java.io or java.nio. Example String content = Files.readString(path);

Also note that when you close System.in, you cannot reopen it. You don't need to close System.in even if your IDE warns you about not closing it.
